# Deleting sub-list that contains duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a large list of uniform-length lists. What is an efficient way to delete component lists that contain duplicates? For three-item sub-lists, I have used the following code:

```
allUnique = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[DeleteCases[listOfThreeItemLists,
  {y_,x_,x_}],{x_,y_,x_}],{x_,x_,y_}];
```

But enumerating all possible pairs for sub-lists of, say, seven items, seems unwieldy. Thoughts?

Comment: `Select[listOfThreeItemLists, Signature[#] != 0 &]`?

Comment: `Select[listOfThreeItemLists, DuplicateFreeQ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
listOfThreeItemLists = RandomInteger[5, {10, 3}]
```

> {{4, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, 5}, {2, 0, 3}, {4, 4, 1}, {3,
>          3, 4}, {1, 4, 2}, {1, 1, 4}, {5, 4, 5}}

In addition to `Select` suggested in comments, you can also use:

```
DeleteCases[listOfThreeItemLists, {___, x_, ___, x_, ___}]
DeleteCases[listOfThreeItemLists, Except[_?DuplicateFreeQ]]
DeleteCases[listOfThreeItemLists, _?(Not[DuplicateFreeQ @ #] &)]
Cases[listOfThreeItemLists, _?DuplicateFreeQ]
Pick[#, DuplicateFreeQ /@ #] & @ listOfThreeItemLists
```

all give

> {{0, 3, 5}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 4, 2}}

Comment: Thank you! Because this is going to be used in a class where Mathematica is a tool, but not the focus of the class, I'm going with the top item here, which looks the easiest to explain to students.

Comment: @KevinAusman, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a bit of linear algebra to make this really fast.

Let's start with an input data set

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 1000000;
m = 3;
data = RandomInteger[10, {n, m}];
```

Here the timing of a `Select`-based approach:

```
a = Select[data, DuplicateFreeQ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.68

And here a variant based on linear algebra

```
b = With[{
      A =  Normal[IncidenceMatrix[DirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range[m], {2}]]],
      u = ConstantArray[1, Binomial[m, 2]]
      },
     Pick[
      data,
      Unitize[data.A].u,
      Binomial[m, 2]
      ]
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

a == b
```

> 0.050
>
> True

How does this work? Well, for a vector `v` of length `m`, the vector `v.A` contains all differences of elements in `v`. `Unitize[v.A]` will replace all nonzero entries with `1`. Since `u` is a vector of ones,  `Unitize[v.A].u` counts the number of pairs of elements in `v` that are duplicate-free. We can do that for all vectors in the list `data` at once with `Unitize[data.A].u`. This way we utilize than matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplications are highly optimized on the machine level and that `Unitize` is also a vectorized (thus highly efficient) function on packed arrays. In the end, we use `Pick` to pick only those vectors from `data` that contain a maximal number of duplicate-free pairs (the maximal number is `Binomial[m, 2]`).

This works also for larger `m` but the performance boost in comparison to `Select`+`DuplicateFreeQ` will decay quite qickly; starting with `m = 10`, `Select`+`DuplicateFreeQ` is faster on my machine. Some reasons for this are that the size of the matrix `A` grows quadratically in `m` and that `DuplicateFreeQ` can short-circuit when it finds the fist duplicate in a vector. Morever, there is potential to use a binary search tree for the implementation of `DuplicateFreeQ` so that `DuplicateFreeQ` might have runtime $O(m \log(m))$ instead of $m^2$...

Answer (score 1):

```
nonduplist[list_?MatrixQ] := Extract[
  list,
  Join @@ (Position[list, #] & /@ Intersection[
   list, 
   Permutations[DeleteDuplicates@Level[list, {-1}], {Length@list[[1]]}]
  ]) // Sort
]
```

A few examples

```
nonduplist@{{a, a, b}, {c, b, a}, {a, b, c}, {b, a, a}, {a, b, a}}
```

> {{c, b, a}, {a, b, c}}

And to replicate @kglr's result

```
SeedRandom[1]; nonduplist@RandomInteger[5, {10, 3}]
```

> {{0, 3, 5}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 4, 2}}